# Google Drive Oauth Request for Permission buttons are disabled

Tags: python, oauth, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload files from my raspberry pi to a google drive through a python script - this was working fine yesterday, but today when it brings me to the Request for Permissions page, both the Deny and Allow buttons are disabled, so I'm unable to get access to my Google Drive and continue the upload.

I've tried logging out, logging back in, and other web servers and google accounts. I'm new to python but this seems like an issue with the web browser?

```py
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

##SET UP GOOGLE DRIVE UPLOAD
gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
g_login.localWebserverAuth()
```

...

```
    file1 = drive.CreateFile()
    file1.SetContentFile('/home/pi/Desktop/earth_test_7/' +
folder_name + photo_name)
    file1.Upload()
    print("Photo uploaded!")
```

This was letting me grant permission before, so I'm unsure if this is an issue I can solve in the code or something I need to fix on the browser end. I'm lost so any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Does your user have the right permissions to use the Drive API? How is your refresh token configurated?